# Why doesn't this work (NavigationService on Singleton)?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, singleton

```
public class Navigator : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private static Navigator _instance;
    private static object _lock = new object();

    public static Navigator Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new Navigator();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
        private set
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                _instance = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private Navigator(){}

    public bool NavigateTo(string uri)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
}
```

It is called in a ViewModel class:

```
 Navigator.Instance.NavigateTo("/NotePage.xaml");
```

So I've got this, and NavigationService.Navigate(..) throws a NullReferenceException.

How can I fix this / what is an alternative? I want to use the NavigationService from a ViewModel class.

I'd prefer a solution without the need for installing more componets (MVVM light). If that is absolutely not possible I'll check out the Messenger / Message class.

**EDIT**
I pretty much gave up. I solved my problem by creating a style for hyperlink button which can wrap around everything.

Comment: You example seems to be missing the private constructor (to hide alternate methods of construction). Can you provide more code?

Comment: the NavigationService.Navigate(..) method does not use the instance? What is the NavigationService relation to the Navigator class?

Comment: I added a private constructor, and that is the complete code. How do I create a relation? I thought being a PhoneApplicationPage was enough.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/05bea462-027b-4e29-8329-dbad000a6ee0

Comment: I dont know how the `PhoneApplicationPage` should be implemented, but from the code provided you might as well just remove the singleton class, because it is not used at all. I am sure that somehow the singleton class is used by the PhoneAppPage (or is intended to), but the code above does not show how. I don't see anything wrong with the Navigator class per se, so I believe that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Could this be of any help? The problem seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929046/navigationservice-throws-nullreferenceexception . I guess that you want to register *something* in your constructor, ie: Messenger.Default.Register<>..

Comment: I tried to do something similar with a silverlight webapp, but the NavigationService requires an instance, so "NavigationService.Navigate" doesnt work, I needed to collect up the instance created when the app started up, when it loaded the first page.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Can you give us some stack info for your null reference exception?  What is null that you're accessing?  Have you tried breaking in the debugger and checking that everything isn't null?

Comment: Where does the NullReferenceException occur precisely? Also, why dont you just use NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative)); alone instead of wrapping it into a singleton? You achieve nothing by wrapping a singleton into another one. You might aswell just call it directly and therefore avoid self-made problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your singleton is not thread safe. look at this implementation:

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html

Comment: as your comment is true it neither answers the question nor will this be a problem in this special case - just see the other comments

Comment: i dont know if this is a problem in his case, but if i see such a singleton i would fix it in any case. i see it as a code smell ;-)